# How to forget authorization credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When you ask for authorization for a certain MVC Action like this:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\Groupname")]
    public string SomeAction()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
```

And the user is NOT a member, the user is asked for valid credentials. This is great functionality that I want to keep.

However.. when these given credentials are valid, these credentials will be used for the entire application until the user of these given credentials changes his password!

How do I force the application or browser to forget the given credentials? Is there some method to apply an 'This is not me..' button?

To my surprise the application will remember these credentials even after a restart of the IIS application AND after a whole reset of the client's browser to factory defaults (?!)

Comment: FormsAuthentication.SignOut. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @IgorSemin: That doesn't seem to work with domain authentication? The application keeps showing the given credentials instead of the logged on windows user.

Comment: What authentication mode are you using?

Comment: Windows Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could came up with was a custom authorize:

```
[Authorize(Roles=@"DOMAIN\APP-ResetToUser")]
public string ResetUser()
{
    return "Active user: " + User.Identity.Name;
}
```

That way you can add users having this problem to this group and let them authorize once with their correct credentials.

This works.. but I would still like to know how the browser or IIS stores this authenticated user.